# How do I apply a regular expression to multiple lines?

Tags: regex

I have a regular expression that grabs the two words I want, but only from the first line. How can I expand the expression to encompass every line.

Regex I have:      `ActivityState\s\s*(\w+).*new ActivityState\s*\(\"(\w+)`

Text String:

```
public ActivityState StartState = new ActivityState("start");
public ActivityState ThisState = new ActivityState("this");
public ActivityState IsState = new ActivityState("is");
public ActivityState AState = new ActivityState("a");
public ActivityState TestState = new ActivityState("test");
```

Desired output:

```
StartState state

ThisState state

IsState is

AState a

TestState test
```

Comment: what language are you using?

Comment: @Andie2302 - he's parsing java source code, doesn't mean its the same as the parser

Answer (score 1):

For a general case, you can add the /g flag in the end of your regex:

```
ActivityState\s\s*(\w+).*new ActivityState\s*\(\"(\w+)/g
```

/g stands for global and it means it wont stop at first match.

See [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lQ3pS7/1)

Depending on your programming language this can be also achieved several different ways, with most languages having this behavior built in on its functions. For instance, in python if you call re.findall(pattern,text) you have the same behavior without needing to specify the /g flag in the pattern.